# Performing a Subquery, Sum and Join in django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, left-join, django-subquery

I have 2 django models which **aren't linked by ForeignKey due to legacy system**.

```
class Parent(model):
    name -> CharField()

class Child(model)
    parent_name -> CharField()
    cost        -> IntegerField()
```

I want to achieve a left join which gives me all parent columns along with sum of cost column from children.
SQL in postgres translates to

```
select parent.name, sum(child.cost) as cost from parent join child on parent.name = child.parent_name group by parent.name;
```

Is there any way to achieve this with django ORM

I have tried a lot of things but https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28296 might be what is blocking.

Comment: Please use a `ForeignKey` to refer to a parent, *not* a `CharField` that joins on the name.

Answer (score 1):

Please use a `ForeignKey` to refer to a parent, *not* a `CharField` that joins on the name. This will guarantee *referential integrity*, avoid data duplication and makes it more convenient to query in Django.

You thus define the models as:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    cost = models.IntegerField()
```

or if the `name` of the `Parent` is unique, you can let it refer to the `name`:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent,
        to_field='name',
        db_column='parent_name',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    cost = models.IntegerField()
```

then you can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `Parent` model with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Parent.objects.annotate(
    cost=Sum('child__cost')
)
```

the `Parent` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.cost` that will contain the sum of the `cost`s of the `Child`s that point to that `Parent`.

Comment: We're using a legacy system where data producer cannot insert such a relationship.

Comment: @th3465: you can also let it refer to the `name` of the parent (see edit). In that case of course the database has poor [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).